iOS default PDF viewer - go to specific page number
Is this actually possible?
I’ve tried long pressing on the page counter, looking in all the menus and typing page numbers into the search box…
On an iPhone using iOS 17, if the iPhone and iPad apps aren’t the same.
UPDATE: Is possible in Books app (using search icon), suspect impossible in standard PDF view.

I think you probably mean the PDFView. It does not have a go to specific page number function afaik, what i do to quickly go to a specific location is press and hold the scroll bar and drag to the place i want.

Thanks. I’ve just found it’s possible if you open the PDF in the Books app instead and using the search icon.
